# Data Argument Not Used By Format String In Error Message

Tags: ios, nsstring

I keep getting the above warning message with this line of code, but can't figure out how to correct it.

```
    *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:NetworkRequestErrorDomain code:ASICompressionError userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decompression of %@ failed because we were unable to write to the destination data file at &@",sourcePath,destinationPath],
NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,
[outputStream streamError],
NSUnderlyingErrorKey,
nil]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a typo: "&@" instead of "%@".

Consider writing your code more like this:

```
NSString *messageText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decompression of %@ failed because we were unable to write to the destination data file at %@", sourcePath, destinationPath];
NSString *streamErrorText = [outputStream streamError];
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : messageText,
                           NSUnderlyingErrorKey      : streamErrorText};
NSError *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:NetworkRequestErrorDomain code:ASICompressionError userInfo:userInfo];
```

With this code format the error would have been on a line by itself and easily found.

Write code for people to read, not the compiler.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that.  This was in an ASIHTTPRequest Library of code I didn't write, so I hadn't done the formatting.